# Not able to read Json Response

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have made a ajax Call which is returning me Values like `{"SessionId":"1","UserName":"Bond","ReferrerUrl":"http://localhost:64132/Test.html","ResponseStatus":{}}` in console.Now i want to read this response one by one which i am trying to do like the below code..

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:64132/Auth',
    data: JSON.stringify(UserDetails),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        debugger;
        $.each(data, function (idx, obj) {
            var UName = obj.UserName;
            console.log(UName);
        });
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("some error");
    }
});
```

but in the console i am getting `undefined`.Please help to resolve it.Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the response data using **`JSON.parse()`** or **[`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)** also there is no need for **[`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:64132/Auth',
    data: JSON.stringify(UserDetails),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
        // parse json string
        debugger;
        var UName = data.UserName;
        console.log(UName);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("some error");
    }
});
```

or you need to set response datatype in  **[`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:64132/Auth',
    data: JSON.stringify(UserDetails),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType : 'json',
    // setting response datatype
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        // parse json string
        debugger;
        var UName = data.UserName;
        console.log(UName);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("some error");
    }
});
```

**Update :** 
If you want to iterate the object then you can use **[`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**

```
$.each(data, function (idx, val) {
    console.log(idx + ' : ' + val);
});
```

Comment: should you parse it first before console.log?`console.log(data);
        data = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Still i am getting undefined only

Comment: @PranavCBalan Worked !! Thanks ..a small update change `obj` to `data`

Comment: @Lara : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

> but in the console i am getting `undefined`

`$.each()` is returning correct results `idx` would be `UserName` , or property name, `obj` would be property value of object

```js
$.each({
  "SessionId": "1",
  "UserName": "Bond",
  "ReferrerUrl": "http://localhost:64132/Test.html",
  "ResponseStatus": {}
}, function(idx, obj) {
  console.log(idx, obj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```